# IF statement in mysql set query

Tags: mysqli

Hy!
I'm new in mysql and I need help. I would like to write a query. I have 2 tables reg_count and form. I would like to SET form.active to "0" IF reg_count "max" and "akt" is equal. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are reg_count and form related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you are using MySQL and form and reg_count are related through a form_id field on both tables, the following should work:

```
UPDATE form f 
JOIN reg_count rc ON rc.form_id = f.form_id 
SET active = 0 
WHERE rc.max = rc.akt;
```

If they are related in a different way, substitute how to join the two tables in the join clause.